# Parse a file with several data coming from an other file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to select lines in b.txt thanks to 3 data in a.txt (A, B, num : xxx).

**a.txt**

```
A B num : 580
A B num : 581
A B num : 582
```

**b.txt**

```
10 E1 A Z1 B Z2 num : 580 Z3 582 Z4
11 E2 C Z1 B Z2 num : 581 Z3 580 Z4
12 E3 A Z1 B Z2 num : 581 Z3 580 Z4
14 E3 S Z1 B Z2 num : 582 Z3 581 Z4
15 E2 A Z1 B Z2 num : 582 Z3 581 Z4
```

**output**

```
10 E1 A Z1 B Z2 num : 580 Z3 582 Z4
12 E3 A Z1 B Z2 num : 581 Z3 580 Z4
15 E2 A Z1 B Z2 num : 582 Z3 581 Z4
```

**MyCode**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pattern[$0];next} ($3 && $5 && "$7 $8 $9" in pattern)' a.txt b.txt > GoodFile.txt
```

what's wrong with that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys of associative array `pattern` are *string concatenations* of the fields and field separators i.e.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{pattern[$0]; next} $3" "$5" "$7" "$8" "$9 in pattern' a.txt b.txt
10 E1 A Z1 B Z2 num : 580 Z3 582 Z4
12 E3 A Z1 B Z2 num : 581 Z3 580 Z4
15 E2 A Z1 B Z2 num : 582 Z3 581 Z4
```

or perhaps more robustly (since it doesn't assume the separators in `a.txt` are single spaces), making use of the unambiguous `SUBSEP` awk variable [as suggested by Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621994/parse-a-file-with-several-data-coming-from-an-other-file/621997?noredirect=1#comment1163507_621997):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pattern[$1,$2,$3,$5]; next} ($3,$5,$7,$9) in pattern' a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: +1 for warning about the case of the field separator in `a.txt`  not necessarily being one space.

Comment: @EdMorton excellent suggestion - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making use of `GNU sed`with extended regex mode turned ON `-E` and autoprint pattern space turned OFF `-n`, we can go about solving it as shown.

First we define some helper shell variables to simplify writing the sed code.

```
$ f='(\S+)' g='\s+\S+\s+' fg="$f$g"
$ Ss='\S+\s+' fs="$f\s+"
$ re="$Ss $Ss $fg $fg $fs $fs $fs"
$ sed -En "
    s/$f/&/6;tb
    s/\s+/ /g;s/^ | \$//g
    H;d
    :b;G
    \#^${re// /}.*\n\1 \2 \3 \4 \5(\n|$)#P
" a.txt b.txt
```

¶ First we identify the line coming from a.txt or b.txt by means of 6th nonspace chunk being present. If yes, it is file b.txt and we jump to label b in the sed code.

¶ Otherwise, for file a.txt, we trim the line and squeeze whitespace. Then store in hold.

¶ For lines from file b.txt, we plug in the $re shell variable, which has been written looking at the line structure of b.txt. Also, while writing it we sprinkled spaces in it for clarity, which we now will have to remove. We print `P` the leading portion of the pattern space should the chunk numbers 3, 5, 7,8, & 9 of b.txt are to be found in a.txt anywhere in one line.